# Is it need to do dataset when I use Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm writing asp.net web application using Entity Framework. Do I need to build dataset while I'm using Entity Framework?

Comment: ***NO!*** The whole point of EF is to *map* the relational data (rows and columns) into nice, directly usable .NET objects - so with EF, you should use **your .NET objects** (and collections / lists thereof) - do **NOT** resort back to `DataSet` and `DataTable` - those are the things you're trying to *get away from* with EF !

Comment: yes...Thanks u so much!  :D